# subclipse in a cluster environment

Tags: eclipse, svn, cluster-computing

I want to set up a svn repository to be used by 4 linux systems in a cluster.
I have installed subclipse plugin for eclipse. created repository in one of the systems.
I am able to use the repository from the same system through eclipse . 
But How can i connect to the svn from other systems across the cluster ???
need some ideas on using URLs to access svn.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you set up Subversion under an Apache HTTP server, so that other machines can access Subversion using the HTTP (or HTTPS) protocol.

Here are some step by step [instructions](http://svn.spears.at/) for installing Subversion and an Apache HTTP server, and configuring Apache.